# Android sqliteException near "CREATE": syntax error

Tags: android, database, sqlite, syntax

I'm developing a database for my app and when I try to add a new user into the database I get this error

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "CREATE": syntax error while

I've looked at other questions and seen that the spacing and quote positioning is very important. But looking at other working examples mine's seems to be correct?

My class below

```
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "FITNESSMATETABLE";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "fitnessmatedatabase";

    private static final String USERID = "_id";
    private static final String NAME = "Name";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "Password";

    //Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 18;

    //The database strings themselves
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME
        + " (" + USERID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + NAME
        + " TEXT, " + PASSWORD + " TEXT);";
```

Looking at the error I believe it's telling me that the quotations around "CREATE" are wrong. Can anyone see anything out of the ordinary?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post full exception and stacktrace.

Answer (score 2):

Varcars aren't available in sqlite. Trying replacing them with TEXT. Check here for sqlite data types http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Answer (score -1):

The following syntax will work for you

```
create table FITNESSMATETABLE (_id integer primarykey auto increment,Name text,password text);
```

Comment: unfortunately I'm still getting the same error with that syntax. I'll keep trying here, Thanks

Comment: Change your code , and directly write  private static final String CREATE_TABLE="create table FITNESSMATETABLE (_id integer primarykey auto increment,Name text,password text);"

Comment: `code` private static final String CREATE_TABLE="create table FITNESSMATETABLE (_id integer primarykey auto increment,Name text,Password text);";`code`

still getting the same error

Comment: Then, that is not the syntax issue. This will come if DB is not create properly . Please check your DB creation